# Problems with connection to the mongodb server v4.0 via SSL

Tags: node.js, linux, windows, mongodb, ssl

I have a trouble. I can't connect to my mongodb server via SSL from Windows 10. I connected to the server from Ubuntu successfully.

Command:

```
mongo.exe --host myHost -u myUser -p myPassword --ssl --sslPEMKeyFile C:\mongo-client.pem --sslCAFile C:\mongo-client.crt --sslPEMKeyPassword myKey
```

On Windows I got error:

> Failed global initialization: InvalidSSLConfiguration Encrypted private keys are not supported, use the Windows certificate store instead: C:\mongo-client.pem

Comment: Did you try decrypting the key first? Seems like windows can't use keys with password here.

Comment: @PierreNectoux i didn't try decrypting, but i successfully connected to a server from Ubuntu with the same command. MongoDB installed on CentOS 7 in AWS

Comment: It's still different binary. If it says that encrypted keys are not supported, I'd assume they are not supported. Try what it suggests - import the key into the system and use --sslCertificateSelector instead. Which version of the client you are using btw?

Comment: @AlexBlexx I'm using v4.0.9 client version. Can you explain me how to use --sslCertificateSelector?

Comment: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/#connect-to-mongodb-instance-that-requires-client-certificates-ssl-options is pretty clear - you import the certificate into the system and let it handle them so mongo will only query the certificate by subject. There are some more details https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.0/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-mongo-sslcertificateselector